Are there "smart" / remotely controlled heating valves without a thermostat?
I want to make my radiators "smart," meaning remotely controllable and integrated into my smart home ecosystem. However, I would like to retain the existing system where the heating is adjusted based on levels (e.g., from 1 to 5) rather than temperature. Essentially, this part of the setup should remain unchanged.
Are there such heating valves? Ones that are "smart" on one hand but still lack a thermostat and operate based on levels instead of temperature?
